# Java Hibernate - assigning the right id for corresponding name in other table

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, annotations

I am doing first step in Hibernate. I have a task I cannot solve.
I have two tables and want to declare connection between them by finding the same String in two tables and assigning the corresponding id.
Table 1 contains list of systems.

```
@Entity(name="system")
public class SystemDsc {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long id;
   private String name;

   public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

   public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And Table 2 contains list of orders.

```
@Entity(name="system_contract")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private long system_id;
    private String system;

    public long getSystem_id() {
        return system_id;
    }

    public void setSystem_id(long system_id) {
            this.system_id = system_id;
        }

    public String getSystem() {
        return system;
    }

    public void setSystem(String system) {
        this.system = system;
    }
}
```

Multiple orders can have the same system value(for axample A01, B07 etc).
List of systems with corresponding ***id*** values is stored in **system** table.
While adding a new order, hibernate should look the same name of the system in **system** table and save corresponding to it id value in ***system_id*** column.

Can it be done by @JoinColumn @OneToMany annotation?

Comment: Cant we first fetch the `system_id` values from `system` table and and then save it?

Comment: yes, i think it can be

Comment: @6rzes Instead of "system_id" and "system" in Order table just have a System object with ManyToOne and JoinColumn. Why does "system_contract" have both "system" and "system_id". Wouldn't just "system_id" suffice?

Comment: I cannot change the way how the data is stored. In system_contract id is a key and system_id value from other table (id key from system).